# Why doesn't the page load when I send an image about 900KB?

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I have a form in PHP to upload two images. I can upload files about 400KB perfecty, but when I try to upload files over 900 KB, it throws the message `"PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR"` in Firefox. I tried using Chrome, Opera, but it is the same thing (it do not load the page).
I checked the configuration in `php.ini` and everything seems correct.

```
upload_max_size= 8M;

post_max_size= 8M;

memory_limit= 8M;

max_execution_time= 300;
```

I don't understand why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you Google on `PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR`? When I do that it tells me its more a antivirus / firewall problem. And if you think its a server problem, always check your log files

Comment: _"I tried using Chrome, Opera, but it is the same thing (it do not load the page)"_ - When you say "it is the same thing", do you mean that you get the error message there as well, or just that it won't upload?

Comment: Using Chrome, it throws the message "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET". Using Firefox "PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR", and using Opera "ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! I checked the logs on the server, and I found the error

*"Requested content-length of 1646786 is larger than the configured limit of 524288, referer: https://web_page.php"*

So, I had to modify the php.conf file to increase the size allowed in the parameter "*LimitRequestBody*" and restart httpd service.

Answer (score 0):

It is realted to proxy settings of your firefox follow the following procedure
Horizontall  three bars > Options > Network Settings > Auto Detect Proxy Enable > DNS over HTTPs enable and save

[First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9eIl.png)

[Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyVMx.png)

[Third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEwOJ.png)

[Fourth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85qrF.png)

[Fifth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boFtP.png)

Comment: Thanks.I changed the settings in firefox, but it doesn't work. I got the same message in Firefox "PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR"